# What is the proper form when lowering the barbell?

Tags: weightlifting, form

I'm taking a look here at this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hch-tH3g7l4&t=0m41s

Specifically this frame:

[image]

It appears he lets it drop with no voluntary tightening of the muscles while it's in descent. When I do this, I tense up my muscles and *resist* the descent as it drops to the ground in my hands. I think that if I were to do it like this person, I would start to develop some socket pain from just letting it jerk like this.

I thought learning shin-to-knee, knee-to-hip, hip-to-breast, breast-drop-to-overhead was it, but no, the descent is important too, no? I want to get it right.

Dropping the bar, IMO, seems less athletic.

Answer (score 1):

The lifter in the video is doing "high-pulls", which are assistance movements for the clean.  He appears to be lowering the barbell from shoulders to thighs (the latter being the "hang" position) with *some* (but not complete) control, which is appropriate.  He is in fact mostly letting it drop unimpeded, but *is* engaging shoulder and back musculature.

Reverse-curling the barbell or otherwise slowing its descent is not essential to the exercise, and could increase his risk of developing an "arm-pull" habit, which is highly detrimental to cleans.

Personally, I don't like that he releases the barbell from the hang position to the floor at the end of the set, but he *is* using bumper plates, so the offense is minimal.